# How to execute Node.js code in the browser context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

**How do I execute client-side JS code within the `page.evaluate()` statement (not just browser JavaScript code, Node.js code)?**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
 const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('button[type=submit]').click();
  });
  console.log('yes') 
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: But aren't you doing just that already? `document.querySelector('button[type=submit]').click();` *should* be executed in browser context

Comment: Or do you mean that the click doesn't happen until the browser is closed? What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter passed to [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) should be a function which will be evaluated in the page context in the browser.

Node.js is server-side code, and is meant to be executed on the server.

You can pass arguments from the Node.js environment to the page function using the following method:

```
// Node.js Environment
const hello_world = 'Hello, world! (from Node.js)';

await page.evaluate(hello_world => {
  // Browser Page Environment
  console.log(hello_world);
}, hello_world);
```

You can listen for the [`'console'`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-console) event to occur in the page context and print the result using [`page.on()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener):

```
page.on('console', msg => {
  for (let i = 0; i < msg.args().length; i++) {
    console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args()[i]}`);
  }
});
```